# PHP Login page not redirecting

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me why my login.php page won't redirect to my member.php page? When I enter login information it connects to my database and just stays on the same login.php page and the username and password I typed in disappears. It never even tries to redirect to member.php. I for sure have member.php loaded on my server and I can get to it by typing it into the browser.  I have searched around for answers from similar posts but nothing seems to help.  Here is the login.php code.  Big thanks in advance if you can help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
<h3>Login Form</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","******","*****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('user_registration') or die("cannot select DB");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."' AND     password='".$pass."'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$dbusername=$row['username'];
$dbpassword=$row['password'];
}

if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;

/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: member.php");

}
} else {
echo "Invalid username or password!";
}

} else {
echo "All fields are required!";
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **warning** you should not store the password in plain text in the database and your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: you need to use exit() after the header

Comment: What does `print_r($user)` and `print_r($dbusername)` and `print_r($pass)` and `print_r($dbpassword)` give you? Are those pairs actually equal?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, as I believe @user3739658 has answered it, you shouldn't make a habit of using PHP and HTML in the same page like this. you should try to remove coding logic from your templates.

Comment: Thank you Daniel A. White for editing that.  User3739658 I have tried using exit() after the header and it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: As @Jhecht said, I'd recommend you to do a page between login.php and member.php. Login would call that page and there would have the code to make the access to db and the redirect.

Comment: @jhecht I only understand part of the php coding I actually got this script from a tutorial.  Seems like it is working properly with my database but won't redirect.  I will try the exit() after the header again.

Comment: @user3765759 please read the answers below. They both say the same thing: PHP cannot send headers after data has been output. Since your PHP is put in between your HTML, the HTML gets sent to the browser and PHP cannot alter the header information after the data has been received by the user client.

Comment: @user3765759 Thanks for the help I got it to work! I took out all the HTML and created a new page called loginform.html that called the login.php script like jhecht said.  Also put the header to the top and added a url like said and its finally working!  Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

A header()  should always be triggered before any content has been placed in the file. Put your

```
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
 }
```

Condition all the way to the top.

Besides that you should put an url in the action attribute to make sure the form gets submitted.  I'm not sure if it works when it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your redirection code to the very top of the page. Before php outputs any html or even whitespace.

If you've already got body content in your output buffer its too late to change your headers - which is what your redirect code is attempting to do.

Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: I will try it out thanks.  No not getting any errors.